# how to get values of object?

Tags: jquery, wcf-client

how do i grab the values of a `Person[]` object?

below is my server side code:

```
public Person[] GetPersonList()
{
   //impl code....
   return new Person[0];
}
```

and my client code:

```
  $("#btn3").click(function (event) {
                $.getJSON(url', { },
                function (data) {
                    alert(data.Name);
                });
            });
```

i am getting this result in Firebug:

jsonp1290528639946( [{"Active":true,"Description":"Initial Test","Id":"1","Name":"Test2010","EndDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","StartDate":"\/Date(1280635200000-0400)\/"}] );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning an array, not just an object, so it would need to be:

```
$("#btn3").click(function (event) {
  $.getJSON('url', { }, function (data) {
     alert(data[0].Name);
  });
});
```

Or for example looping through them:

```
$("#btn3").click(function (event) {
  $.getJSON('url', { }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, person) {
      alert(person.Name);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Nick, you think the data i am getting is looks kinda strange numbers?

Comment: @Chicagoland - can you clarify?

Comment: if you look at the array i have start/end date `","EndDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","StartDate":"\/Date(1280635200000-0400)\/"}] );
`

Comment: @Chicagoland - ah, that's the way WCF is serializing dates, check out this question on turning those into JavaScript `Date` objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-json-date